# the jdbc driver did not return a connection. This is very often caused by an incorrect jdbc url

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to connect to AWS redshift and use Sql workbench.
i enter my URL

```
jdbc:redshift://testskyeng.cz2jvchnn3c7.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev
```

enter my login and pass
and try to connect, but the error:

```
the jdbc driver did not return a connection. This is very often caused by an incorrect jdbc url
```

here the screen.
Please help 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI1F7.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the Postgres JDBC driver with Redshift???

Comment: @fvu Redshift is Postgres compatible. It should work fine.

Comment: @D.joe did you enable the "Publicly Accessible" flag on the Redshift cluster?

Comment: i found and checkbox enable

Answer (score 3):

I found this post because I had a similar issue and wanted to share my solution.
In my case the error was the JDBC driver, I was using the wrong version, after I downloaded the correct file from Amazon (link below), I changed the driver path  on "Manage drivers" and it worked fine.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 2):

For my error when I added `jdbc:postgresql://` to the beginning of the endpoint that AWS provides it worked.